# Calculating gpa is returning error

Tags: java

Hy guys i will need a quick help with my asigment. I tryed to debug this code and i dont know how do i got this error but when i try to calculate gpa it is sending me 0 instead of value from switch.
If user is pressing A and credits 4 it needs to return 4 * 4 but for letter A i am receiving 0

```
public class Gpa{
    private int sumOfCredits;
    private int sumOfPoints;
    private int points = 0;

    public Gpa(){
        sumOfPoints=0;
        sumOfCredits=0;
    }

    public static int calcPoints(String grade) {
        int points = 0;
        switch (grade) {
            case "A":
                points = 4;
                break;
            case "B":
                points = 3;
                break;
            case "C":
                points = 2;
                break;
            case "D":
                points = 1;
                break;
            case "F":
                points = 0;
                break;
            case "a":
                points = 4;
                break;
            case "b":
                points = 3;
                break;
            case "c":
                points = 2;
                break;
            case "d":
                points = 1;
                break;
            case "f":
                points = 0;
                break;
            default:
                points = -1;
        }
        return points;
    }

    public int getSumOfCredits(){
        return sumOfCredits;
    }

    public int getSumOfPoints(){
        return sumOfPoints;
    }

    public void addToTotals(String grade,int credits){
        sumOfCredits =+  credits;
        calcPoints(grade);
     sumOfPoints =sumOfPoints + points * credits;
    }

    public double calcGPA(){
        double gpa = sumOfPoints /sumOfCredits;
        return gpa;
    }
}
```

and this is my tester class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ComputeGpa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Gpa gpaC = new Gpa();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter grade (one character): ");
            String grade = scan.next();
            System.out.printf("Enter credits: ");
            int credits = scan.nextInt();
            gpaC.addToTotals(grade, credits);
            System.out.printf("Sum Points: %d", gpaC.getSumOfPoints());
            System.out.printf("\tSum Credits: %d\n", gpaC.getSumOfCredits());
        }
        System.out.printf("GPA: %.2f", gpaC.calcGPA());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check out this useful article on [How to Debug Small Programs](http://lingualeo.com/es/jungle/how-to-debug-small-programs-by-eric-lippert-310227#/page/1) and then get that [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) (seriously).

Comment: `sumOfPoints =+ + points * credits;`?

Comment: Multiple use of `=+` looks like you aren't runnng your code in an IDE.

Comment: i have changed it to sumOfPoints =sumOfPoints  + points * credits;
Still doesent work.

Comment: The please [edit] the question with the newest code and errors you get

Comment: @cricket_007 no we need to write in jgrasp for school

Comment: @cricket_007 `=+` compiles.  As does `=+ + + +`.

Comment: But, and this may be relevant to the OP: they don't mean "increment." `sumOfCredits =+  credits` is equivalent to `sumOfCredits = credits`. To increment, you'd want `sumOfCredits += credits`

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
 double gpa = sumOfPoints /sumOfCredits;
```

Is integer division in java and will return an integer value. Chances are it is always a value between 0 and 1, which will be equivalent to 0 after being casted to an integer. See if casting them to double fixes it.

```
double gpa = (double)sumOfPoints / (double)sumOfCredits;
```

You are also redefining points on each loop here:

```
    public static int calcPoints(String grade) {
    int points = 0;
    switch (grade) {
```

Which means that instead of changing the global variable `points` you are changing the local variable `points`. So you need to remove that local variable points so it uses the global one, also you dont need to return anything so just use void:

```
public void calcPoints(String grade) {
     switch (grade) {
       //cont
```

Comment: No, it is still 0

Comment: @ZeroOne check out the edit I made, the problem is with the scope of your points variable. Make those changes and it will work.

Comment: I have found this just before your comment. Thanks alot, if i knew this earlyer it would saved me from 2 hours trying to fix this code.

Comment: @ZeroOne no problem, it's usually something simple. Consider marking it as the accepted answer if it helped you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

in your calcGPA() method you are doing integer division when you want to do floating division. You either have to cast the sumOfPoints variable or the sumOfCredits to a double.